# The controller with the name <controllername> is not registered, AngularJS trying to open $modal

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am working on a web app which is developed prior to me with AngularJS using typescript in lieu of JS.

I have a controller, with an assigned template I'm attempting to open in a modal using $modal.open.

For some reason I get the following error and no answer on Stack Overflow, or anywhere else seems to work or is relevant to my scenario.

Here is the error...

> Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'AddWeightCtrl' is not registered.
>   https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=AddWeightCtrl
>
> ```
> at angular.js:138
> at $controller (angular.js:11680)
> at setupControllers (angular.js:10711)
> at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10496)
> at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9835)
> at publicLinkFn (angular.js:9700)
> at angular.js:1967
> at Scope.$eval (angular.js:19396)
> at Scope.$apply (angular.js:19495)
> at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1965)
> (anonymous) @ angular.js:15570
> (anonymous) @ angular.js:11849
> $apply @ angular.js:19500
> bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1965
> invoke @ angular.js:5143
> doBootstrap @ angular.js:1963
> bootstrap @ angular.js:1983
> angularInit @ angular.js:1868
> (anonymous) @ angular.js:36426
> trigger @ angular.js:3522
> ```

I have coded the modal.open as follows...

```
export function openAddWeightModal(data: AddWeightCtrlParameters,
    $modal: mm.foundation.modal): angular.IPromise<apsCommands.addWeight> {

    return $modal.open({
        template: template,
        controller: 'AddWeightCtrl as vm',
        resolve: {
            params: () => data
        }
    }).result;
}
```

...and I have followed the existing pattern that we used for declaring the controller class and exporting the name of the module upon creation, like so...

```
class AddWeightCtrl {
    private $modalInstance: mm.foundation.modalInstance;
    form: angular.IFormController;

    constructor(
        $modalInstance: mm.foundation.modalInstance,
        $q: angular.IQService,
        params: AddWeightCtrlParameters,
        $stateParams: StateParams,) 
    {
        this.$modalInstance = $modalInstance;
    }

    submit() {
    }

    cancel() {
      this.$modalInstance.close();
    }

    private updateStatus() {
    }

    pass() {
    }

    fail() {
    }

    notApplicable() {
    }
}

export default angular.module('aps.controller.AddWeight', requires)
  .controller('AddWeightCtrl', AddWeightCtrl)
  .name;
```

This is working everywhere else in our app, and I cannot find where I'm going wrong.  Please advise if you think you may know a solution.

Comment: I changed the name in the code to make it more generic.  That is not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs when the [`$controller()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) service is called with a string that does not match any of the registered controllers.

Causes for this error can be:

1. Your reference to the controller has a typo.
2. You have not registered the controller.
3. You have a typo in the *registered* controller name.

Another common cause is that the controller was overwritten by specifying the module dependency twice.

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> angular.module("app",[]).controller("AddWeightCtrl", addWeightCtrl);
> function addWeightCtrl() {};
>
> angular.module("app",[]).controller("ctrl", function() {});
> ```

In the above example, `angular.module("app",[])` is called twice. The second call overwrites the `app` module and the `AddWeightCtrl` controller.

BETTER

```
 angular.module("app",[])

 angular.module("app").controller("AddWeightCtrl", addWeightCtrl);
 function addWeightCtrl() {};

 angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", function() {});
```

In the above example, the dependencies are defined only once.

From the Docs:

> ## Creation versus Retrieval
>
> Beware that using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the module `myModule` and **overwrite any existing module named `myModule`.** Use `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Modules - Creation versus Retrieval](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)
- [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $controller:ctrlreg](https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=AddWeightCtrl)
- [AngularJS angular.module Function API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

Comment: thx for the answer.  I've decided to consume and modify an existing component in lieu of the approach in this question, so I can't confirm this answer as providing the final solution to my specific problem.

Comment: However, I am going to up-vote due to the high quality of this answer. Thx again georgeawg.